# Check for existence of file with wildcard-expansion in R

Tags: r, wildcard, file-exists

I want to check if a folder exists based on string-values in a variable.

I need to use wildcard function though as the folders I wanna check can differ in names but will always include the contents of the string-variable

**Problem:** If I apply `file.exists` function to `Sys.glob` function it will always return `TRUE` since `Sys.glob` (*which I use for wildcard expansion*) will only work its magic on the files that actually exist and skip the ones that don’t.

Imagine there are two folders in my `path_root`

```
path_root/hihi_test1_hoho

path_root/haha_test3_hehe
```

```
variable <- c("*test1*", "*test2*", "*test3*")

file.exists(
Sys.glob(
file.path(path_root, variable)))
```

In the example, the output would be

> [1] TRUE TRUE

I would want the result to be

> [1] TRUE FALSE TRUE

since there is no *test2* folder.

So I would basically just like to use wildcard expansion in the `file.exists` function but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read the question and now have a better understanding of what is required, please try:

```
path_root <- "C:/Users/User/Documents"
variable <- c("somepattern.*", ".*R")
#Search for pattern in directories:
grepl(paste(file.path(path_root, variable), collapse = "|"), list.dirs(path_root, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE))
```

Comment: please explain your answer.

Comment: list the subdirectories of the base_path variable that contain some pattern. If nothing returns those directories don't exist, if they do return the names.

Comment: apologies the question reads find files, i read it as find directories. answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for not making my request clear enough.
sapply has a similar problem: I embed Sys.glob function all results are TRUE but the ones that are FALSE are not displayed as Sys.glob had been applied before I check for their existence with dir.exists. If I use it without Sys.glob it lists all the directories I want but they are all false, because it doesn't recognize the * as a wildcard character

Comment: No, my mistake, please try the answer above and see if it works as desired

Comment: As above (see answer box) use ".*" for wildcard matching, my code has worked as required on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, the answer above worked for me - although I used


```r
grepl(paste(variable), collapse = "|"), list.dirs(path_root, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE))
```


because otherwise it wouldn't recognize the pattern. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, sorry for the confusion.